# Graph database modeling with sets of typed items

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, modeling

In the real world problem, I've got some bins, sets and items. The objective is to fill each mandatory bin with exactly one item of correct type (T1 - T3) and fill the optional bins with any number items of correct type (T4 - T5). The sets may include items of any type. The sets may therefore include items of the same mandatory type, which is a problem. I'm trying to model such that traversing the graph corresponds to picking sets and items efficiently. But (as in the first image) it fails whenever a set happens to include two mandatory items of same type.

The sets are forcing to pick exactly one of the mandatory items of same type, along with the other items.

[image: Problem description]

A straight forward solution would be to take each set including mandatory items of same type and create a new set for each of those conflicting items, including all other items with no conflict. However, the number of sets increases exponentially with the number of conflicts.

[image: Solution 1]

Any modeling suggestions, thoughts or comments are welcome!

Comment: This sounds more like a logic (Prolog) problem than a graph (Neo4j) problem.

Comment: Yeah, it is not a graph problem, it is a modeling problem. It's not a question on whether or not this is solvable in itself, but rather if it's possible to model such that it can be solvable using a graph (with e.g. Neo4j, or any other graph database)

Comment: Can the same item be in multiple sets and/or multiple bins? And are given a specific number of mandatory/optional bins?

Comment: Good question. Same item can be in multiple sets but not in multiple bins. There are a finite number of both mandatory and optional bins (if I understand your question correctly). @cybersam

Comment: Yes, my last comment was garbled somehow. So, I take it we cannot create new bins when solving this problem? Also, how do we identify the bins that need to be filled by each set -- can we just pick any appropriate bin?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the bins are static in that sense. Also a good question. Each mandatory item "belongs to" a certain bin, e.g. m1 belongs to T1, m2 to T2 and so on. The other items can be placed in any optional bin. So, e.g. in the solution example, we need to find more sets to fill T3.

Comment: What is the desired output? Do you want each output record to contain a collection of sets that satisfy the bin-filling task?

Comment: What is the desired returned output? Do you want each output record to contain a collection of sets that satisfy the bin-filling task? Aside from the output, do you also want the query to actually somehow modify the DB to "fill" the bins?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I want to ouput a collection of sets satisfying this task. If it's even possible to do (aside my propsed naive solution). As for now, it doesn't need to change the DB